# SQL counting and identifying records that have more than one variant not duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of people (their UserIDs) and the locations (the SiteIDs) they worked at during the month. I'm interested in whether any UserIDs worked at multiple SiteIDs during the same month.

So, there can be daily records such as below. (I omitted the date field as that's unimportant; assume these are all from the same month):

| UserID | SiteID |
| --- | --- |
| 2023 | 1311 |
| 2023 | 1311 |
| 2023 | 9876 |
| 1824 | 9876 |
| 1824 | 9876 |

I want to do a simple count of any UserIDs that have more than one SiteID. Just a figure i.e 0, 1 or 12, or 150. So if the table was just the five records above, the Count=1 i.e there is one UserID (2023) that has 2 variant SiteIDs (1311 and 9876).

Just to be clear, I'm not after a count of records, nor a count of duplicates or frequency. It's the number of people who have worked at more than one location during the month.

Then, if there are some variants, I'd like a separate query that to show their UserID and SiteID

So a separate SQL query that would corroborate the Count=1 above and show:

| UserID | SiteID |
| --- | --- |
| 2023 | 1311 |
| 2023 | 9876 |

Comment: Please post what you have tried so that we may best assist you in fixing it.  Consider adding appropriate data AND the expected result data set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the following two step query here:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT UserID
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY UserID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SiteID) > 1
) t;
```

The inner query finds all `UserID` having more than one site.  The outer query counts those users.